# Vectorizing a Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have csv file that I am reading into a Python Pandas Dataframe. I want to vectorize the operation to run data cleansing on columns with a set of user defined functions for certain columns and append the results to the dataframe.

I can read the records and process them 1 by 1 but want to vectorize the operation by Pandas operating on the 1 whole column with a function.

Input Dataframe

```
   A   B   C   D
0  a   b   c   d
1  t   f   h   e
2  j   r   y   k
```

I want to perform data cleansing (`DC*`) on columns columns `A, B and C`.

```
   A   B   C   D   DC1-A   DC2-B   DC3-D
0  a   b   c   d    1       0       -1
1  t   f   h   e    1       -1      0
2  j   r   y   k    0       1       1
```

The above matrix shows what data was cleansed and what could not be cleansed.  In columns `DC1-A, DC2-B and DC3-B`, values of 1 show data cleansed, 0 shows data not needed to be cleansed and -1 data could not be cleansed.

Comment: Ok, what is the issue?

Comment: Could you exlain in more detail how the `DC - A/B/D` columns are constructed? where do their values come from? How are they related to the remaining columns?

Comment: I wanted to be able to vectorize the "data cleansing" of columns A, B, and D and put the results in DC1-A, DC2-B and DC3-D.  Results Data columns show the "cleansing" and and/or any data checking.  I wanted to work a the column level and not process a record\row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was a way to vectorize the processing of a 2D array by columns.
The way to do this is outlined in Sofia Heisler's article:

https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

To vectorize a Pandas Dataframe (df):
    df['distance'] = function1(40.671, -73.985, df['latitude'], df['longitude'])

To vectorize a Numpy Dataframe from a Pandas Dataframe (df):

df['distance'] = function1(40.671, -73.985, df['latitude'].values, 
   df['longitude'].values)

function1 will need to be able to work with 1D vector for parameters 3 and 4

function1 would return a 1D vector that processed the latitude column in the example above.

Thanks